# Jasper Reports + PDF generation issue

Tags: fonts, pdf-generation, jasper-reports

I have a jasper report that I'm displaying. Now I have an icon to get the same report in PDF.

Now when I deploy the code in an OS with Tomcat it works fine, but the problem I'm facing now is that, we have created a VM Image of Ubuntu without UI.

And when I try to download the report as PDF, i get an error, after extensive search on the Web and here, I found that the fonts were missing and hence this problem.

Now I've hard-coded the path of the font and put the true-type font also in the same path of the report folder. But still I'm getting an error.

Here is the code I've put in the JRXML file

```
<font size="20" isBold="false" fontName="Verdana" pdfFontName="/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/WallCloud/jsp/dashboard/reports/Helvetica.ttf" isBold="false" isPdfEmbedded ="true"/>
```

and here is the error I'm getting

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:515)
```

This is on a the line

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conn);
```

And here is my pdf generation code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer" %>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader" %>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager" %>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager" %>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint" %>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign" %>
<%@page import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport" %>
<%@page import="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream" %>
<%@page import="com.abc.xyz.utils.DBConnection" %>
<%@page import="org.apache.commons.collections.*" %>
<%@page import="org.apache.jasper.JasperException" %>

<form name='frmReport' method='POST'>
    <%
    try {
        Connection conn = null;
        DBConnection dbConn = new DBConnection();
        conn = dbConn.getSimpleConnection();
        String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/jsp/reports/Report.jrxml";


      JasperDesign jasperD = JRXmlLoader.load(path);
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperD);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"Report.pdf\"");   
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conn);
                    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, baos);

                response.setContentLength(baos.size());
            ServletOutputStream out1 = response.getOutputStream();
            baos.writeTo(out1);

            out1.flush();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception se) {

        }
    %>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. We need the following:

1. Edit /etc/apt/sources/list
2. add the following line

   deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy multiverse

   deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy multiverse

   deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates multiverse

   deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy-updates multiverse
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts

This solves the problem and the PDF is also getting generated.

Answer (score 1):

To ship the required fonts with your report templates when deploying them in the target application you [need to use the font extensions](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/fonts/index.html).

Regards,

Gilberto